# Onvif - GetStreamUri says "XML well-formed violation occured"

Tags: xml, onvif

How can I build Onvif GetStreamUrl message? I have tried millions of possibilities, here is one of them:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <s:Header>
    <Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <UsernameToken><Username>onvif</Username>
      <Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">tFvFfoo7ZZhmKv61tTBJ4agS/lM=</Password>
      <Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">NTcxNjg1NTQwNzg2Mzcx</Nonce>
      <Created xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2016-07-14T14:02:27Z</Created>
      </UsernameToken>
    </Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <GetStreamUri xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl">
      <StreamSetup>
    <StreamType>RTP-Unicast</StreamType>
    <Transport>
      <TransportProtocol>UDP</TransportProtocol>
    </Transport>
      </StreamSetup>
      <ReferenceToken>profile_1_h264</ReferenceToken>
    </GetStreamUri>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The official specification is here: http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/media/wsdl/media.wsdl#op.GetStreamUri.

Is there anyone who could help me?

Comment: If the whitespace in front of `<?xml` really exists in your data, try removing it.

Comment: It does not, and I also do not use whitespaces in the message at all.

Comment: Did you find out what the problem was? I'm getting the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to make the envelope yourself you can use the following tested template and make http request containing the SOAP envelope.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <s:Header>
        <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="SecurityToken-906d1a56-c091-4d33-8afa-04445dd123ff" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">THHcq7prwwf/42S+A5tuorg/RMY=</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">f11vJWByh7IJBvZRi46Qeg==</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2016-10-19T05:42:47Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <GetStreamUri xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl">
            <StreamSetup>
                <Stream xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema">RTP-Unicast</Stream>
                <Transport xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema">
                    <Protocol>UDP</Protocol>
                </Transport>
            </StreamSetup>
            <ProfileToken>2_def_profile1</ProfileToken>
        </GetStreamUri>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But using onvif media service you can get the profiles, choose one of them and call GetStreamUri method with your preferred StreamSetup and the token of the chosen profile.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `TransportProtocol` instead of `Protocol` in your request body for version 10 of the ONVIF specs (https://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl/media.wsdl).

Next to that, I had the same problem regarding “XML well-formed violation occured” in the GetStreamUri call. Adding the xmlns scheme to `Stream` and `Transport` fixed the issue.

```
<Stream xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema">RTP-Unicast</Stream>
<Transport xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema">
    <Protocol>UDP</Protocol>
</Transport>
```